# Files getting deleted in GIT while merging

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two branches in GIT-Branch A and Branch B.
Branch A contains 10 files
Branch B contains 15 files out of which 10 files are common in Branch A.

While I am merging Branch A to Branch B can see the below behavior:
 1. The extra 5 files which are not common are getting deleted.
 2. Extra lines in common files in Branch B are getting deleted.

While I am merging Branch B to Branch A can see the below behavior:
 1. The extra 5 files are not getting added to Branch A.

I have tried this out n both GIT bash and Tortoise GIT and can see the same behavior. Can you please suggest how do I handle this scenario without the files getting deleted or changes getting missed.

Answer (score 2):

When you merge two branches, Git looks at exactly three points to consider what to merge: the two heads, and a third location called the *merge base*, which is usually the point at which the branches are forked.  Everything it produces in the result of the merge is the sum of the changes between the merge base and each head.  In other words, if you make a change on one side and not the other, the resulting merge will contain the change.

In your case, in one branch you have deleted files and in the other branch you have done nothing with those files.  Since deleting files counts as a change, it's incorporated into the result.

If you don't want to delete those files, then adjust branch A so that it doesn't delete them and then do the merge.  This is the best and easiest way to solve the problem.

Alternately, you can do what's called an *evil merge*, which is a merge where you tamper with the result Git would normally have produced.  If you want to do that, perform the merge as normal, then run `git checkout B -- file1 file2 file3 file4 file5`, where the files are the paths that were deleted.  Then run `git commit --amend` to squash the changes into the merge commit.

Answer (score 0):

The *branch names* are not important here.  What matter are the *commits*.

The trick is to draw your commits and find the *merge base*.  The merge base is where your branches join up.  Let's draw your actual branches.  Of course I have to *guess* what your commits are; you haven't shown us your repository and its commits.  But they probably look something like this:

```
          I--J   <-- BranchA
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- BranchB
```

Here, each uppercase letter stands in for some actual commit hash ID.  Use `git log --graph BranchA BranchB` to have Git draw the graph for you, vertically with newer commits towards the top, instead of the way I drew it, horizontally with newer commits towards the right.  The `git log` command will include the actual hash IDs as well (albeit abbreviated).

Note how, at some point, the two branches join up.  In the graph I drew above, they join up at commit `H`.  **This commit is the merge base** and the merge base is the key to merging.

What you are doing is comparing the contents of commits `J` and `L`.  One of those commits has five more files than the other.  **That's not important.**

What matters is what you get if you:

- First, compare `H` vs `J`.  This tells you what you—or whoever—changed in the series of commits leading from `H` to `J`.
- Then, compare `H` vs `L`.  This tells you what you—or whoever—changed in the series of commits leading from `H` to `L`.

Git is going to *combine these two sets of changes*.

What you will find, once you find commit `H` (or whatever its actual hash ID is), is that *one* of these two comparisons says *delete five files*.  That is one of the set of changes that Git is combining.  (Based on your description above, that's `H`-vs-`J`: the deletion happened on the top line.)

The *other* of the two comparisons says: "you don't need to do anything at all to those five files".  It's easy to combine these two instructions: "do nothing" plus "delete" equals "delete".  So `git merge` will *delete those five files*.

Your best bet is to make a new commit on Branch A that says *put those five files from the merge base `H` or from commit `L` back*:

```
          I--J--M   <-- BranchA
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- BranchB
```

Now, comparing `H` vs `M` says *don't do anything with those five files*.  Comparing `H` vs `L` also says *don't do anything with those five files*.  It's easy to combine these two sets of instructions: Git will keep those five files, that are the same in all three commits.

As [bk2204 answered while I was typing all this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60219367/1256452), you can go ahead and make the merge, then modify it—or you can run `git merge --no-commit` so that Git doesn't actually make the final commit yet, then modify it before committing—so that the merge result keeps the five files, despite the more natural result.  Then you get:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M
         \    /
          K--L
```

where the snapshot in merge commit `M` merges the changes, but keeps the five files.  (The branch name that moves to point to `M` depends on which branch you `git checkout` before you run `git merge`.)

Last, if there's some reason not to make a restoring commit *before* the merge—which is usually the best practice—and you don't want to make an "evil merge" that requires repeating this trick if you ever use `git rebase --rebase-merges`, you can go ahead and make a merge commit `M` that deletes the five files, but then put them back in a subsequent commit.  For instance, suppose you use `git checkout BranchA; git merge BranchB` so that you get:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- BranchA (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- BranchB
```

You can now make one more commit that simply puts the files back:

```
git checkout <hash-of-H> -- file1 file2 ... file5
git commit -m "restore five files that were erroneously deleted in commit <hash>"
```

for instance, which results in:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N   <-- BranchA (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- BranchB
```

where commit `N` has the five files back.

(Use `git checkout BranchB` or `git checkout hash-of-L` if you want to take the five files from commit `L` instead, though if there was no modify/delete conflict, that means those five files match in commits `H` and `L`.  So it won't matter which one you use to get the five files from: use whatever command is easiest.  Note that the name `BranchB` here only works correctly because we did the merge on `BranchA`, so that the name `BranchB` did not move.  If we did `git checkout BranchB; git merge BranchA`, the name that moved to point to `M` would be `BranchB`.)